# height of user display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys I want to know if i could implement something like this in my side:

1. To check the height of the users window or display
2. And if it's for example smaller than 800px,
3. Then a javascript code should not be executed

I already read about mediaqueries but, I really don't know how to use it on a jquery code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `window.innerHeight`:

```
document.ready(function(){
  if (window.innerHeight < 800){
    //Code here
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much i just had to replace the window.innerHeight < 800
with window.innerHeight > 800

Answer (score 2):

You can jQuery **[height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)** function or `window.innerHeight` to find out window height.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/juPHr/1/)**

```
if($(window).height() < 800)
   return;

//You code here
```

**Edit:** As mentioned by Cerbrus, it is better to use javascript `window.innerHeight` here

```
if(window.innerHeight < 800)
  return;

//You code here
```

Comment: Do you _have_ to use jQuery? jQuery just uses `innerHeight`. (Also: typo in your `return` statement)

Comment: Ehm, there's still the typo: `retrun` --> `return`

Answer (score 1):

use jquery [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/).. go to the link if u want to read more about `height()`

```
if($(window).height() < 800)
{
     //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this sometimes when I want to know about the user's viewport:

```
var PageDimensions = (function () {
    var Width;
    var Height;
    var getDimensions;

    function pagedimensionsCtor() {
        if( getDimensions === undefined ){
            getDimensions = document.createElement("div");
            getDimensions.setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden;position:fixed;bottom:0px;right:0px;");
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(getDimensions);
        }
        Width = getDimensions.offsetLeft;
        Height = getDimensions.offsetTop;
    }
    pagedimensionsCtor();

    function Reset() {
        pagedimensionsCtor();
    }

    function GetHeight() {
        return Height;
    }

    function GetWidth() {
        return Width;
    }

    return {
        Reset: Reset,
        GetHeight: GetHeight,
        GetWidth: GetWidth
    };
})();
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Vb7xz/